# What is the probability that a random function is invertible?

Tags: randomness, one-way-function

Having a random function - $R\in{}\mathcal{R}$

s.t.
$R:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow{}\{0,1\}^n$.

What is the probability that $R$ is invertible?

I know calculating it suppose to be straight forward, but I'm struggling with it a bit.

Comment: Hint: [An invertible function is a permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection)

Comment: Hint: Count the number of functions and the number of permutations from $n$-bit strings to $n$-bit strings.